# Which 'single-step' multiple comparison test is being employed within R multcomp::glht?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, multiple-comparisons

When performing a general linear hypothesis test using the `glht` function within the R `multcomp` library.

For example:

```
glhtResult <- multcomp::glht(myModel, linfct=myContrastMatrix)
```

Then extracting estimated differences between the coefficients using `summary()`, a multiple comparison test can be applied by passing an argument to `adjusted=`, with `"single-step"` being the default.

```
summary(glhtResult, adjusted="single-step")
```

However, it is my understanding that the term single-step refers to a family of multiple comparison test, not a single method. For reporting purposes, I would like to know which test is applied, but the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/multcomp.pdf) doesn't specify.

Does anyone more familiar with these methods know what test is being used? Is it inferred from the contrast matrix? i.e. If the contrast matrix is constructed using Tukey comparisons, is Tukey HSD used for the single-step multiple comparison test?

Thanks

Comment: "That is, the "mvt" adjust method in lsmeans is the same as the default single-step P value adjust- ment in multcomp.".  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/vignettes/using-lsmeans.pdf .  Dunno if that helps.

Comment: Also, no, the "tukey" matrix in *glht* just means that all treatments are compared against all other treatments.  As far as I understand, it's not related to Tukey HSD.

Comment: It does, thanks. Also this [paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/132311758.pdf) gives some more background on the multivariate t method.